# ASP.NET MVC 3 How to inject Javascript into the master layout

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying out the new razor view engine from MVC 3.  The issue that I am having is that I have Javascript that is page specific.  I normally have all my Javascript code before the  tag closes.  I was thinking of putting a section just before I close the body tag on my master layout.  Some thing to the effect of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   @RenderSection("JavaScript")
</script>
```

But VS2010 underlines it in green.  So which ever pages uses this master layout can have it's Javascript injected Here.  How would you guys do it?  The reason why I want to do it like this is because then I can add JavaScript from the master layout also in here, other I will have to define a separate script tag just below the @RenderSection.

When I do the following then VS gives me a warning (I don't like warnings):

```
Validation (HTML 4.01): Element 'link' cannot be nested within element 'link'.
```

Here is my code for the above warning:

```
@section HeadSection
{
    <link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/button/assets/skins/sam/button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/datatable/assets/skins/sam/datatable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
}
```

How can I get these warnings away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use @RenderSection("head", false) in my _layout page.  Then you can inject whatever you want in the head of the page (including script)...and by using false you make it optional on all of your view pages.

Comment: @According to the guys at Yahoo it best practices to have your Javascript at the bottom of your page.

Comment: Yes, this just ensures that all of the DOM is loaded before your script fires.  I use jQuery a lot and there is a helper method for this, making the need to add it to the bottom irrelevant.  However, if this is the case then just add a RenderSection("footerscript", false) and put everything in there.

Comment: You're not auto closing your link tags ;)  you need the forward slash at the end of the <link/> element.

Comment: How can I accomplish this same thing without using the Razor View Engine in MVC 3?

Comment: I'm following this suggestion exactly and I'm still getting the warning on my view page where I have the @section defined.

Comment: @Ryan: The reason to put your JavaScript at the bottom is because the page will render faster if your script doesn't have to be downloaded first. http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I'd do, according to the best practices you should place your scripts at the bottom of the page.

_Layout.cshtml

```
<html>
    <head>
        @* ... *@
    </head>
    <body>
        @* ... *@        
        @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
    </body>
</html>
```

MyView.cshtml

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myScript.js")"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

Comment: This has got nothing to do with the question.

Comment: The question reads as follows: "ASP.NET MVC 3 How to inject Javascript into the master layout" how come my answer isn't related to the question? You might want to write your concrete question in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off or modify VS's XHTML validation checking:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/23/431350.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the `link` tags.

Like this:

```
@section HeadSection
{
    <link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/button/assets/skins/sam/button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/datatable/assets/skins/sam/datatable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```

And then follow Ryan's answer.

Comment: The doctype has nothing to do with the question. I am using HTML 4.01.