# Javascript and Javascript librarys usage with Razor and MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

What is the proper way to setup my javascript blocks in Razor and MVC? 
I know that the best practise now it to put the javascript calls at the bottom of the page but what about my javascript in my partials especially my "$(document).ready".  If my reference to jQuery is not called prior to that it will error.

1. Is there a server tag that will just put references to all of my javascript files in a particular folder into the page?
2. Is there a way to wrap my javascript in my views (partial views) so that it will put it after the javascript references?

I apologize for this being vaque.  But a link to a good tutorial on how I am supposed to handle javascript in Razor MVC especially for someone who does a bunch of Jquery/Ajax/Json style.

PS I have my stuff working but I feel there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This Question would probably give you a good idea:

[ASP.NET MVC 3 How to inject Javascript into the master layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418445/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-inject-javascript-into-the-master-layout)

```
<html>
    <head>
        @* ... *@
    </head>
    <body>
        @* ... *@     
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script
        @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Pretty much have an optional Section at the bottom of your page after jQuery is loaded.  Then in your views, if you need to include Javascript it can be loaded after the jQuery script.